# Looking for a movie from 80s with glowing green orbs causing kids to shrivel up from the feet on up

Tags: story-identification

I think it was the 80s. All I remember were these floating, green/black orbs that at one point came to hover over some kids in bed. Then the kids feet started shriveling and rolling up the legs. I don't remember if it showed what happened then, like the like were absorbed or souls sucked into the orb or something like that.

For some reason I've associated this for a long time with the Body Snatchers so maybe it was around the same time. Since then I've learned it wasn't that movie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like [**Strange Invaders**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Invaders) from 1983. The movie was a campy tribute to 50's movies like [Invasion of the Body Snatchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers).

> The small town of Centerville, Illinois is actually a haven for alien
>   invaders who take human form, shoot lightning, and transform victims
>   into glowing blue orbs for "storage".

The orbs you're thinking of were blue, but otherwise your description is pretty accurate. Here's the scene with the kid being shriveled into an orb:

[image]

*Images courtesy of [Kindertrauma](http://www.kindertrauma.com/?p=29843) website*

Comment: Yup, looks like that's it, and it's as horrific as I remember as a kid. After I posted I looked on youtube and it's there too, so I may have to watch later. WHere did you get these images?

Comment: @user26270 - found them on a page that reviewed the movie. The URL was kinder-something if that helps.

Comment: @user26270 - found the site again, added source under image with link

Comment: WOW oh my god, i remembered seeing this in the early 80's and was to terrified i actually thought it may have been a suppressed memory. I saw it on TV/Cable in a hotel with my family visiting San Francisco. they were all asleep and i watched this creepiest movie i have ever seen...ive seen lots, but i only recently tried to recall what the hell was that and was listening to an interview with Linda Moutlon Howe (from https://www.earthfiles.com/) on aliens last week and it re-sparked my curiosity. Im kinda glad it was a real movie not a screen memory. BUT it resonated with me to this day...in Oc

Comment: I've been searching for this movie for over 20 years!