# 80’s Movie where an alien turns two children into floating glowing balls

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've had this movie scene stuck in my head for 20 years now and it's driving me nuts.

SCENE #1 Dad hears kids (two small boys) screaming from bedroom. Runs in to look. He sees a humanoid monster/alien standing over the bed wearing an old McDonald type overalls outfit (redneck look). The monster/alien holds its hand over the bed and it shows the boy start shriveling up (Very graphic, like only an 80s horror scene can be). The boys then turn into these floating glowing balls, which come up out of their corpses. The father hits the monster/alien with something (maybe baseball bat) and it hits the floor dead.

SCENE #2 Father talking to someone (friend/therapist maybe) and says the boys/kids (now just two floating glowing balls) just follow him around the house.

Given the age, and how disturbing I remember the scene being, I'd say the movie/short story was definitely from the mid to late 80s. I don't know if it was from a typical movie or from a Creepshow (short stories) style movie. Maybe even a tales from the Crypt show. I just don't know. The fact that it's from the 80s (golden era of horror) makes it nearly impossible to guess.

Comment: Shriveling corpses and glowing orbs sounds like one of the Phantasm movies.

Comment: It seems that [Looking for a movie from 80s with glowing green orbs causing kids to shrivel up from the feet on up](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93489/looking-for-a-movie-from-80s-with-glowing-green-orbs-causing-kids-to-shrivel-up) is a duplicate of your question, in that it asks about the same film. This question may now be closed of a duplicate of that. Please note that this is not a bad thing!

Comment: As it turns out this is a duplicate, and the other post did, in fact, answer my question. However, I never would have found it had it not been for this post, so credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a topic from 5 years ago that is similar to yours. Not really sure because I don't know the movie but it could be **Strange Invaders (1983)**.

You can find the topic [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93489/looking-for-a-movie-from-80s-with-glowing-green-orbs-causing-kids-to-shrivel-up).

Comment: Ah, ya beat me to it, LeaG! :-)  It definitely is Strange Invaders from 1983.  Here's a link to the film on Youtube.  You can see the kids floating as glowing balls of light at about the 1:07.00 mark.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Km89bden8s

Comment: OMG! Thank you guys so much. I never would have found this. Sad thing is after 30+ years I finally just got to see the scene again on YouTube and it was so cheesy lol. Thanks again!